# Detecting when iOS screenshot is added to album

Tags: ios, photosframework

I came across the app [LIKEtoKNOW.it](https://www.liketoknow.it). They have an interesting feature where the user takes a screenshot outside of their app (i.e. instagram), then their app will detect the screenshot and send a push notification to the user.

Any ideas on how this is achieved?

My assumption is that they're monitoring the 'screenshots' photo album, and when a new screenshot is added they execute some code on it. If the code returns a certain result, then a local push notification is created. However in this case, wouldn't there be limits to how and when the monitoring of the 'screenshots' photo album can occur? Or can it occur indefinitely?

Comment: Have you looked at PHPhotoLibraryChangeObserver? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photos/phphotolibrarychangeobserver

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the  ["Photo Library Observer API"](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photos/phphotolibrarychangeobserver) and the *PHAssetMediaSubtypePhotoScreenshot* media type to be notified of screenshots as they are taken in different apps / contexts.

[This gist](https://gist.github.com/Koze/c93a7a951a7ee1d1cb80) shows how to filter screenshots  only from the library.